# Manual activation of membership level with paid membership pro

Tags: php, membership

I want to use "pay by check" checkout method. So, I don't want automatic activation of the membership level during checkout. I will activate the level after getting the check. How Do I deactivate auto activation? I found a plugin called `pmpro-check-levels` from [github](https://github.com/strangerstudios/pmpro-check-levels), but which seems not working. I have install and configure the two line i.e removing comment and inserting level id as follows:

```
global $pmpro_check_levels;
$pmpro_check_levels = array(1,2,3,4);
```

what is the problem? could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you may have already found an answer by now, but you cannot disable activation of a membership level with that plugin (at least not out of the box).  That plugin is just to allow you to offer a pay by check method.  What you are doing with these lines:
`global $pmpro_check_levels;
$pmpro_check_levels = array(1,2,3,4);`
 is saying that you want level 1, 2, 3, and 4 to pay by check.  It will however automatically assign them those membership levels regardless of whether or not the check has been received.

If you do not want them to have access to the features of those four membership levels before payment is received you will need to create a new membership level (i.e. level 5) and set that as the only level in the array.

ex: `$pmpro_check_levels = array(5);`

You will not want to assign any special access or privileges to that membership level.  That will essentially keep them how they were before signing up for that level.  Once you receive payment you will need to manually adjust their membership level to one of the others on the Admin side of your website.

The documentation may not have been as clear to you at first glance, but it should all be covered [here](https://github.com/strangerstudios/pmpro-check-levels/blob/master/pmpro-check-levels.php)